# Write Access Violation (ptr was nullptr) while returning a pointer in a function that was used to create a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

```
int foo(int *A);

int main()
{
  int* ptr = nullptr; 

  *ptr = foo(ptr); // Line X

  return 0;
}

int foo(int *A)
{
  A = new int[10];
  return *A;
}
```

When I perform this line of code it gives me a write access error the moment it returns the function call to on **line x**. It states `ptr` was `nullptr`.

I don't understand what this means. I'm trying to dynamically create an array inside this function, return a pointer back to the main, and then modify the values inside.

Comment: change `foo` to `int* foo(int *A){A = new int[10]; return A;}` and use `ptr = foo(ptr)`!

Comment: (1) You aren't modifying the pointer in `main`. (2) Even if you were to change it by passing a reference, you'd still have potential undefined behavior, depending on the version of C++ you are compiling as.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why undefined behavior?

Comment: @songyuanyao - In C++14, which side of the assignment expression is sequenced before the other?

Comment: Thank you, it worked out nicely. I always get pointers confused and mixed up a lot!

Comment: @MartinBonner That's not really the right choice for duplicate. OP's error was due to assigning a value to a dereferenced `nullptr`. This would be a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763617/224704

Comment: OP: What was your problem?  Was it "what does 'null pointer assignment' mean?" or "why is my pointer still null?".  The duplicate @CraigYoung suggests answers the first question; I closed the question with a duplicate for the second question.